# Windows 8 TextBlock in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml

```
<FlipView Name="flipView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource FlipViewStyle1}">
            <TextBlock Name="answerT" Text="{Binding question}"/>
            <FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,137,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="flipTxt" Text="{Binding question}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

I have the above FlipView in XAML defined. I want to get the information that i have in the "flipTxt" TextBlock in a string in C#.

Tried with VisualTreeHelper but i can't seem to understand exactly how it works.

As well, tried to create another textblock (answerT) that would read the same info and get the text from that one. Didn't work either.

Thanks

LE:
This is how i did the binding, i get the data from MobileService.

```
private IMobileServiceTable<myObj> obj_tb = App.MobileService.GetTable<myObj>();
private ObservableCollection<myObj> obj_it;


var res= await obj_tb.ToListAsync();
obj_it = new ObservableCollection<myObj(res);
flipView.ItemsSource = obj_it;
```

Comment: Since you are binding the value, don't you get the binding from the `SelectedItem`

Comment: you can get it from `FlipView's` DataContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing your FlipView is binding to its collection correctly you can access the SelectedItem in code on different events eg SelectionChanged event

```
private void flipView_SelectionChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (flipView != null)
        {
            var item = flipView.SelectedItem as MyObj;
            string question = item.Question;
            string answer = item.Answer;
        }
    }
```

Possible MyObj

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

or as youre using MobileServices you would probably have this if using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

```
public class MyObj
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Question")
    public string Question { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Answer")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tried something simillar as well, dellywheel. But what if i would have 2 TextBlocks in the DataTemplate, one binded to "question" and another to "answer"?

Correct me if i am wrong, but at the moment aren't you selecting the whole textblock while i am interested in the Text property only?

Comment: Ideally your myObj that you use for binding would have 2 properties for Question and answer. I'll update the answer to show what I mean